# Fetch all NFTs owned by wallet address with web3.js

Tags: node.js, ethereum, web3js

I am new to blockchain.

I have done a little bit research and here's my steps to fetching a list of NFTs owned by certain wallet with web3.js

```
balance = ERC721.methods.balanceOf(walletAddress).call();
objects = [];

for (i = 0; i < balance; i++) {
    tokens.push(await ERC721.methods.tokenOfOwnerByIndex(walletAddress, i).call());
}

for(i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++){
    objects.push(await ERC721.methods.tokenURI(tokenIdList[i]).call());
}
```

I can fetch a list of ERC721 token URI with the above methods but the perfomance is really poor. I am wondering how OpenSeas can achieve that with light speed performance on the same feature.

Comment: what package are you using to get the ERC721.methods

Comment: @ccurves I also am interested in which package is he using, did you find it out?

Comment: I think that he is using OpenZeppelin: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/token/erc721

Answer (score 1):

As in most cases, storing or caching the data lowers the load time.

You can store the `objects` value in DB (such as MongoDB) and update it regularly - if you have a manageable amount of `walletAddress` items, or just for some high priority items.

You can even subscribe to event logs (in your case the `Transfer` event) on the token contracts and not have to poll the changes. (Maybe poll just as a fallback in case your subscription fails.)

For the rest of `walletAddress` items (the lower prioritized), you can cache them in a temporary storage (such as Redis). So the first load is going to be slow (because it's going to load from the external resource - as your current snippet is doing), and the other loads (until the TTL expires) are just going to be loaded from the cache, not hitting the external resource.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [multicall](https://www.multicall3.com/)
It allows to make batch contract calls.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Agree here, it would be better

Answer (score -1):

this will return all the tokens owned by this wallet in an array without having to loop:

```
await ERC721.methods.userOwnedTokens.call(walletAddress)
```

good luck! hope this helped

Comment: i don't think i see this as part of the token standard

Comment: This methos doesn't exist anywhere in erc-721..

Comment: there are multiple new API functions that fetch all owned NFTs of a certain address on different EVM chains, 
1- alchemy : https://docs.alchemy.com/docs/how-to-get-all-nfts-owned-by-an-address#:~:text=To%20get%20all%20NFTs%20owned%20by%20an%20address%2C%20use%20the,to%20get%20NFT%20ownership%20data.
2- Moralis : https://docs.moralis.io/moralis-dapp/web3-api/nft-api#getnfts